# Why is Linux ASLR weak?

Tags: linux, aslr

Wikipedia says Linux kernel has a [weak form of ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Linux) by default and only adding PaX or Exec Shield patches enables complete ASLR.

What is the weakness of default ASLR in Linux kernel? Has it been fixed/improved in recent versions? If not, is there a reason why the mainline kernel chooses to not provide a complete implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia article continues:

> This places the stack base in an area 8 MB wide containing 524,288
>   possible positions; and the mmap base in an area 1 MB wide containing
>   256 possible positions.

The latter is way too small to be effective, and an attacker only needs to probe 256 addresses in one segment to find the `mmap()` address pointer.

What the article doesn't mention is the limited use of ASLR in Linux. Traditionally the 2.6 kernel only used ASLR for (network) processes in specific memory areas (when PIE compiled) while loading the VDSO to a fixed address. Such a measure is only effective if *all* the addresses are randomized. Newer kernels have better support for address randomization. Note that various Windows versions did the exact same thing.

Comment: Thank you. Are the randomization spaces still same in latest kernel? If so, why are they not changed?

Comment: @Chandru They have changed in the 4.8 release. Now including support for random mappings, virtual allocations and physical mappings. This has also made its way to the KASLR http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1607.3/00404.html

Comment: @YorickdeWid KASLR is a completely different technology of questionable effectiveness, related only to ASLR in name.